# Easily manage and duplicate folder permissions on Windows Server AD

Tags: permissions, windows-server-2012-r2, network-share

**Context:** Imagine I have 3 group of users (X, Y and Z), and the following folders:

**[Folder] : [Groups who have access]**

**Folder A** : X, Y, Z
---- **Folder 1** : X, Y
---- **Folder 2** : Y, Z
---- **Folder 3** : X, Z
--------- **Folder 3.1** : X

@Edit: The idea is create a **Folder A** for each projetct, so they are better organized and categorized. Examples of folders 1, 2, 3 could be Manuals, Doccuments, Active, Obsolete, those kind of stuff..

**Situation:** I must duplicate A an uncertain amount of times and I'd like to keep the folder structure and permissions (e.g. when I create B it already have 1, 2, 3 and 3.1 folders, with same permissions as A).

Windows Server does **not** preserve the permissions when copying and pasting folders, and so far I've been using `.bat` scripts to do the job.

However, I think it consumes a lot more time to do that than it should.

@Edit:

**IMPORTANT**: The folder's (A, B, C, ...) structure and permissions **are the same**, but the files in it **are not**.

---

**Questions are:**

1. Is there an easier way of duplicate A?  Perhaps a software that helps me managing this..
2. Is there any way of, if A child's permissions come to change, I automatically "deploy" them to the other copies (B, C, ...)?

Assume that folder 1, 2, 3 and 3.1 all have the same name on A, B, ..., Z.

Thank you very much.

Comment: merge content, dont overwrite your folder A. problem will be solve

Comment: @yagmoth555 what do you mean by merge content? put everything on folder A?

Comment: I will rewrite my statement, why not using DFS to replicate it ?

Comment: As you got the minimum, an AD, then the DFS is the way to go, and learn to do it. I added an answer

Comment: Replicate the same Folder A content to several servers, or duplicate the structure to several parallel hierarchies on the same server? You seem to be using 'replicate" and "duplicate" interchangeably; to me they have subtly different meanings.

Comment: @roaima Duplicate the structure to several parallel hierarchies on the same server. I'll edit the question to make it clearer. Sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest way to do this assuming you already have a "template" folder is with the built-in [robocopy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145(v=ws.11).aspx) tool.

If you want to duplicate the folder and all of the files, you can use it like this.  The `/copyall` flag is what copies the permissions and `/mir` makes sure the destination includes no more and no less than what was in the source.

```
robocopy .\FolderA .\FolderB /copyall /mir
```

If all you want is the folder structure and none of the files, you might do something like this. The `/e` flag explicitly includes empty directories and `/xf *` excludes all files.

```
robocopy .\FolderA .\FolderB /copyall /e /xf *
```

If you want to get fancy and/or not have to rely on a template folder, your best best would be to script the folder creation and ACL settings via PowerShell. I won't go into details here as there are plenty of examples out there.

Answer (score 0):

DFS is the answer, as it will keep both side correct. You can get report of the replication, you can use DFS namespace to allow user that are nearer to a server to use that nearer server's share automatically, etc... and most of all, it's a simple 10/12 click setup to do in a wizard.

A tutorial's there: http://www.techunboxed.com/2014/07/how-to-set-up-dfs-replication-in.html

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think he's looking to replicate an existing folder to a different server.  He's looking to duplicate an existing project folder for a new project that keeps the same structure and permissions.

Comment: @RyanBolger You couldn't be more right. I really appreciate the answer, but it's not what I'm looking for